# inner join vs stored procedure or Function sql server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, inner-join, sql-function

I have this schema :

[image]

When I want to display the `Attend` table, instead of `DoctorId` and `PatientId`, Employee Name And Patient Name display.

Like this:

- id
- Patient name
- Doctor Name [== Employee name]
- Start
- End

First way is to use an inner join :

```
select 
   a.Id, p.Name, a.Name, a.Start, a.End 
from 
   Patient as p  
inner join 
   (select 
       e.Name, at.Id, at.Start, at.End, at.PatientId
    from 
       Attend as at  
    INNER JOIN 
       Employee as e on at.DoctorId = e.Id) as a on p.Id = a.PatientId
```

Second way is to use a function or stored procedure - send in the `id` and get back name

```
 select 
    a.Id, 
    FindDoctor(a.DoctorId) as Doctor, 
    FindPatient(a.PatientId) as Patient, 
    a.Start, a.EndTime 
 from  
    Attend AS a
```

Which is the better? Which is the optimized approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, SQL engines do a better job of optimizing queries than of optimizing function calls.  I would suggest that you stick with the query, at least at first.  This also makes it easier to understand performance issues that might arise.

By the way, there is no need for a subquery for what you want to do.  SQL Server is pretty smart, so it probably doesn't affect performance.  However, you can write the query as:

```
select at.Id , p.Name , e.Name , at.Start, at.End 
from Patient p inner join 
     Attend at
     on p.Id = at.PatientId inner join
     Employee as e
     on at.DoctorId = e.Id;
```

Some people like to embed such queries in stored procedures.  If you want to encapsulate this logic, I would suggest a view or table-valued function instead.

Comment: it is fast. 
A Question? : now , in general , is difference to use inner join or stored procedure?

Comment: @amirabdollahi . . . I don't understand the question.  The two are not interchangeable.  An `inner join` is (typically) part of a `select` statement.  A stored procedure is independent code that might contain `select` statements, but it might contain many other things as well.